# Prestashop create two modules in one installation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In my module I need to extend prestashop core `CarrierModule` and `PaymentModule` because it has shipping and payment parts. So I planed to create two different modules separate and build them in one folder and install once. 
I need to know how could I make install script to install two modules (one after other).

This is install function for one module

```
public function install() {
        $flag = parent::install();
        if ($this->name !== 'urbitbasic')
            $flag = ($flag && $this->registerHook('displayRightColumnProduct'));

        return ($this->installer->installTables() &&
                $this->installer->installCarriers() &&
                $this->installer->installWarehouseCarriers() &&
                $this->installTabs() &&
                $this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader') &&
                $this->registerHook('actionCarrierUpdate') &&
                $this->registerHook('actionObjectCarrierUpdateAfter') &&
                $this->registerHook('displayCarrierList') &&
                $this->registerHook('displayOrderConfirmation') &&
                $flag);
    }
```

Basically I need to create one module, one installation file that install two modules.

Comment: Two modules in one folder??

Comment: @sarcom I mean I've two modules that need to install as one

Comment: Sorry, I understand that you have two modules in one folder `build them in one folder` :).

Answer (score 1):

You must install almost one module, choose you which one, in that module you can do this procedure:

```
public function install() {
    $flag = parent::install();
    if ($this->name !== 'urbitbasic')
        $flag = ($flag && $this->registerHook('displayRightColumnProduct'));

    $first_install = ($this->installer->installTables() &&
            $this->installer->installCarriers() &&
            $this->installer->installWarehouseCarriers() &&
            $this->installTabs() &&
            $this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('actionCarrierUpdate') &&
            $this->registerHook('actionObjectCarrierUpdateAfter') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayCarrierList') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayOrderConfirmation') &&
            $flag);
    // Now we install the second module
    $mysecondmodule = Module::getInstanceByName('{thenameofyoursecondmodule}');
    $second_install = $mysecondmodule->install();

    return $first_install AND $second_install;
}
```

Comment: @rcom  can I create two different installer files? because I need to `extend` both `PaymentModule` and `CarrierModule`.  
so how can I create second module according to the your answer ?

Comment: If you have created two modules, you must have two different files, e.g.:
`urbitbasic/urbitbasic.php`
`urbitplus/urbitplus.php`

You cannot have two modules in the same folder, it's a PrestaShop MVC rule.

And to answer to your question, yes, no can, you have to create a second module :)

Comment: Thanks for the  advise. 
when I create two different files and two modules, can I create a common file to install both modules at once ? Because user should install one.

Comment: Maybe I'm not been so clear, in one of two modules you install the second as well, the two modules have to work 'independently', what you want to do it's only a simplify to user/merchant :)